# Get a Enum with a string in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I want to get the value from an enum after the user selected 'action' in a picker view.
So I have as string: `selectedGenre = "action"`.

How can I get "28" from the case?

```
public enum MovieGenres: String {
  case action = "28"
  case adventure = "12"
  case animation = "16"
  ...
}
```

I need to have something like this:
MoveGenres.("selectedgenre").rawValue

Comment: [Swift Language Guide: Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145)

Answer (score 12):

First of all this is how you define your `enum`

```
enum MovieGenre: String {
    case action
    case adventure
    case animation

    var code: Int {
        switch self {
        case .action: return 28
        case .adventure: return 12
        case .animation: return 16
        }
    }
}
```

Now given a string

```
 let stringFromPicker = "action"
```

You can try to build your enum value

```
if let movieGenre = MovieGenre(rawValue: stringFromPicker) {
    print(movieGenre.code) // 28
}
```

> As you can see I renamed `MovieGenres` as `MovieGenre`, infact an enum name should be singular.

Comment: Alright thanks for that! But what if I need code in string format?

Comment: `var code: String {
        switch self {
        case  .action: return "28"
        case .adventure: return "12"
        case .animation: return "16"
        // the rest   
        }
    }`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `rawValue` to get the `Strings`:

```
MovieGenres.Action.rawValue // 28
```

And to get it from a String:

```
let twentyEight = MovieGenres(rawValue: "28")
```

Another tip, it´s Swift convention to name your cases with lowercases, like this:

```
 MovieGenres.action.rawValue // 28
```

**Update:**

```
enum MovieGenre: String {
    case action
    case adventure
    case animation

    var value: Int {
        switch self {
            case .action: return 28
            case .adventure: return 12
            case .animation: return 16
        }
    }
}

let action = MovieGenre(rawValue: "action")?.value // 28
let adventure = MovieGenre(rawValue: "adventure")?.value // 12
let animation = MovieGenre(rawValue: "animation")?.value // 16
let none = MovieGenre(rawValue: "none")?.value // nil

if let value = MovieGenre(rawValue: pickerValue)?.value {
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: How to select that with the string?

Like: Moviegenres.("SelectedGenre").rawValue

Comment: @CoenWalter, `let twentyEight = MovieGenres(rawValue: "28")` check the updated answer

Comment: But what if i don't have that value. The user is picking: "Action". I only have that string. From there I need 28 for a API function. So if they pick another genre. I need another value.

Comment: @typeoneerror, no it´s not! OP´s example is using a string as rawvalue and not an Int. The examples in my answer is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you wanna do something like this instead... There is a difference between rawValue and value of the case you wanna get... so at first you wanna get the case:

```
//Get the value from picker
let selectedValueString = MovieGenres(rawValue: picker.value).myDesiredValue
```

Now to the enum:

```
//The raw Values are the same if you choose String type
public enum MovieGenres: String {
      case action
      case adventure
      case animation

       var myDesiredValue: String{
        switch self{
          case action:
           return "28"
          case adventure:
           return "12"
          case animation:
           return "16"
          }

        }
    }
```